# How to filter active record result based on the return value of a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm aware of the ActiveRecord scopes, which helps to add filters by applying conditions to the SQL query. My scenario is such that, I have a bit complex business logic that cannot be easily translated into conditions in SQL query for filtering efficiently. I'd like to hook into some ActiveRecord methods if possible, so that the object is returned, only if the business logic decides that it's valid. I want to make it transparent to other developers, who would otherwise have to call this method every time when they query using the model.

E.g.
`Book.find(10)` or `Book.where(name: 'Macbeth')` should return nil/empty array if `validate_book` returns false and return the result only if the method returns true.

I don't want each developer using the `Book` model to call `validate_book` every time they have to query. Could this be done transparently in ActiveRecord?

Comment: You would have to fetch the records and then iterate and filter through them in Ruby which is a potential huge performance/scaling problem. Postgres for example lets you write functions in Ruby and many other languages and run them in the database.  But its hard to actually give a good answer to this question since its a pretty clear cut [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yes, I'm conscious of the performance / scale problems associated with this. Unfortunately, there are complex business logics that have to be run in the web service to make this decision. I'm okay with iterating and filtering it in Ruby. Is there a clean way to do it transparently without every developer working with the model having to call this filtering method explicitly?

Comment: I don't think "a way to do it transparently" is even a good goal. It should not be transparent at all - it should be extremely obvious to other devs that your methods are pulling everything out of the database and that you will be working with an array instead of an ActiveRecord::Relation that is like a lazy loading object that maps the relational model of a database to an object oriented language.

Comment: @max, `validate_book` method is something that should be applied by default, unless some one wants to override this default behavior. A similar analogy would be to think this as something that decides whether a particular user can see this object or not. So, it should be applied by default to prevent other devs from making a mistake of not calling this method and leaking information.

Comment: You still don't get it though. Since you're loading the records and iterating through them you no longer have a relation that you can apply query methods to. You cant  just pop your logic in an think that it will work like any other collection.

Comment: You could put the logic for validate book into a scope and set it as the default scope for that model. That way it will be applied, by default